# Puppet-4.2: Loading Plugins from Modules

Tags: puppet

I have a bunch of custom types and providers written and tested against Puppet 2.7.whatever. The said types/providers sit in a dedicated module, which contains only lib subdirectory with all extensions under it. The custom types are tested from another module/class under the same modules subdirectory. As far as I understand, this used to belong to 'best practices'. Now, with Puppetserver 2.1.1 at least two things have changed:

The extensions defined in a different module are not loaded. If the class using custom types is declared in manifest under module 'test', and the custom types/providers are under module '_ext', I get `Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter name failed on Resources[<my_custom_type>]`. The extensions are not even downloaded from the server. As soon as I symlink _ext/lib to 'test/lib', it works. Symlink removed, everything is purged from cache on the next agent run. So, **what are the new rules of loading plugins defined in modules?**

I have several providers for different types, using the same command-line utility. Eventually, I have factored out a few class instance methods into a parent class that inherits from Puppet::Provider and is 'required' and is passed as 'parent' argument to Puppet::Type.type(:).provide function. The require uses the relative path, like in require `'puppet/provider/<parent>.rb'` It works with Puppet 2.7 but Puppetserver 2.1.1 throws an excepton:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not autoload puppet/type/<custom_type>: Could not autoload puppet/provider/<custom_type>/<custom_provider>: no such file to load -- puppet/provider/<parent>`

So, **what is the best way to include a parent class in this scenario?** The full path to class will be different on the server and on the agent, so this is hardly an option.

I have used the default settings on server and minimal agent configuration. pluginsync is set to true on the agent, but that's default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1st problem:

module name starts with underscore and is ignored (no idea why). But changing `_ext` to `ext` makes all extensions to be downloaded, cached, etc.

2nd problem, a dirty fix:

add the absolute path to ruby-load-path in puppetserver.conf:

```
ruby-load-path: [/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby, /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/<myenvironment>/modules/ext/lib]
```

No idea how to make Puppetserver (or rather, the JRuby interpreter) to look into *every* `lib` subdirectory for Ruby files, though.

On the client, everything runs smoothly once the 'evaluation' is brought to order on the server.